# WSDualHttpBinding - Java or SoapUI Client

Tags: java, wcf, wsdl, soapui, wsdualhttpbinding

I have been struggling with this problem for more than a week.
I have a third-party WCF webservice which works with WSDualHttpBinding. I have wsdl file from them, and I am trying to communicate. I used:

1. Metro which generates Java code. I tried it but it didn't work.
   There was a problem something like *{tempuri.org}//WebServiceName is
   not a proper name. List of webservices are:...*
2. SoapUI - I tried to communicate, and I got 202 accepted. I used wireshark and it seems like webservice can't proceed the soap xml properly. I am not really sure if soapUI is supprting WSDualHttpBinding.

I really appreciate any hints, articles or solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure dual binding is interoperable with clients other than WCF. I read once that Metro (WSIT) stack for Java supports it. But the safest will be to use a WCF client.

The reason is that the dual binding assumes the client should get messages from the server in a callback endpoint. This is not so standard, also in terms of defining this properly in a WSDL file. You might be able to get away with it by setting up a dedicated server on your client side waiting for the WCF response. But the wiring will be time consuming.

If you own the server you might want to make it more explicit that the client is supposed to have a server endpoint to get callbacks to or you could use some WCF router as an intermediate.

UPDATE: check [this link](https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/wshttpdualbinding_a_non_interoperable_binding) to read why WSDualHttpBinding is not interoperable with Java

Comment: The thing is that I can't use WCF client ;) Yeah i have one and it works but the main goal is to communicate via Java

Comment: Then I would recommend to either change the server binding or use a WCF proxy/router in the middle. Not every WCF configuration can be consumed by Java. I have updated the answer with a link that explains why this binding is not interoperable with java.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response :) Anyway there is a response for the link you've updated : [link](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/haroldcarr/archive/2009/04/metro_interoper.html) So after reading this I thought there is a way to use both Java and wsDualHttpBinding